# What type are 2016 Subaru Forester OEM brake pads?

Tags: brakes, subaru, forester, brake-pad, material

Facing replacement of rotors and pads in my 2016 Forester, I consider non-OEM parts. Thus, I was trying to figure out what type are the OEM pads (i.e., semi-metallic, ceramic). I could not find this information online.

Any idea of the answer?

Comment: Call up any Subaru dealer with a shop and they will tell you what was OEM on your model. In general premium models get assembled with premium parts such as ceramic pads. Even if yours does not have OEM ceramic I would highly recommend ceramic pads. I've really only known spark plugs to cause issues if you don't get the exact OEM type such as copper, platinum, or iridium. If your car came with copper then replace with copper as the other two can cause issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went on and had the service done in a local shop. While paying, I asked the mechanic, and he looked it up on his computer. Apparently, the (at least the Limited Edition) Foresters come installed with ceramic pads.